# Очистка содержимого формы после отправки

Tags: javascript, ajax

Не могу понять как очистить форму после отправки данных на почту, на форумах внятного ничего не нашёл

```
    $("body").on("submit", "#skidka", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize() + "&skidka_r=1",
            success: function (data) {
                // $("body").find("input[type='tel']").mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
                $('input[type="tel"]').mask("+7 (X99) 999-99-99", {
      translation: {
          'X': {
              pattern: /9/, optional: false
          }
      }
});
                form.find('.uspeshno').html('<p class="result_d">Ваше сообщение получено, мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время!</p>');
                event.stopPropagation();

            },
            error: function (error) {
                form.find('.uspeshno').html('<p class="modal-form__success-text">Произошла ошибка. Попробуйте позднее.</p>');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: А банальный form.reset() не работает?

Comment: @AlexeyTen если бы работал, я был бы счастлив)

Comment: `form.get(0).reset()` или `form[0].reset()`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте стандартное https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

```
form.reset();
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что он обновляет страницу после отправки

Comment: @is73dre `event.preventDefault();` должен делать своё дело. На крайняк поставьте `return false;`  в sucess.  Но если даже при всех этих `preventDefault` перенаправляет, значит это прописано на серверной стороне